# ZF2 Mapping ResultSet of a Join-Statement into different Objects

Tags: zend-db, resultset, zend-framework2

when it comes down to increasing performance, reducing the amount of single SQL-Queries is one part of that.

Now let's assume a very basic example: i have a **blog**-table and a **user**-table. Each blog is referencing to a user by a given primary key.

A statement could be like

```
SELECT blog.title, blog.text, user.name FROM blog, user INNER JOIN on blog.user_id = user.id
```

Now my Blog-**object** i would like to have a $user-property which is a User-**object**

My Question: Are there inbuilt features within ZF2 to handle such a case? Or would i be needed to either manually map each field of the result into my objects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no inbuilt features with ZF2 to do this - you should consider Doctrine 2 or Propel if you want that.

With `Zend\Db` however, you could write such SQL statements within your mapper class and then use an `ArraySerializable` hydrator to populate the blog entity. The blog entity's `populate()` could then choose to create a user object with the user data that is passed to it.

Comment: Thanks Akrabat! I think your second proposal will be what i'll be going with for now, as last time i've checked doctrines ManyToX-Relationships weren't working as well as i'd liked them to (in terms of form element support).

Comment: Maybe you guys can make an exemple of it? I need more details to make this in my application! tnks!

Comment: I agree, please an example :)